# Node.js: How to transparently require and export submodules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to gather a lot of dependencies in one repository called, lets say `module`, so I only need to have one dependency for other repositories. Is that possible:

index.js in `module` repository to gather submodules

```
const submoduleA = require('submoduleA')
const submoduleB = require('submoduleB')

exports.submoduleA = submoduleA
exports.submoduleB = submoduleB
```

index.js in `another module/library` where I need all submodules, so I require `module`

```
const { submoduleA, submoduleB } = require('module')
```

Is that possible in any way? I know it's not a huge benefit, but would be nice to explain how all the submodules came about to be available.

What I want to be as transparent as possible is the `module` repository. Only requiring it to get all the other dependencies, but not getting in the way of normal syntax for those dependencies.

Comment: var module = require('module') and for call function use module.FUNCTION_NAME()

Comment: or you can use submoduleA = module.exports =  require('submoduleA') and now you can use submoduleA anywhere in your project

Comment: @KaushikMakwana Can you elaborate a little more on the second one, so I get it fully?

Comment: This is possible, but not recommended.  You are throwing away a bunch of advantages of modularity just to save a little typing.  Instead, you're going to make every one of your files dependent upon a whole block of modules whether they actually are or aren't really dependent upon them all.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you wrote?  Anything?

Comment: @Wyck It doesn't work =) Or at least, I'm not getting it to work.

Comment: And, what doesn't work about it?  "Doesn't work" is not a very useful description of a problem.  It gives us no debugging info, no description of the error, nothing at all to go on.

Comment: FYI, this mechanism will not work with the newer ESM `import` and `export` as you can't have programmatically calculated exports (the exports have to be statically declared).

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, but it's part of some more advantages. A lot of my repositories need the same bundle and test devDependencies, and I'm trying to both standardise it a little bit and not have version bumps create noise wherever I have dependencies.

Comment: Please try this `module.exports = { submoduleA, submoduleB }` instead of `exports.submoduleA = submoduleA; exports.submoduleB = submoduleB`.

Comment: It's unclear (pun intended) what you mean by _"transparently"_.  Can you please be specific about what you require to be _transparent_ about it?

Comment: @Wyck Edited the question, but answer here to: What I want to be as transparent as possible is the `module` repository. Only requiring it to get all the other dependencies, but not getting in the way of normal syntax for those dependencies. So app.js (alternate) seems good, I'm just not getting it to work. But easier to try more if I know it should/could work.

Comment: @jfriend00 The error I got was: "  TypeError: batr.test is not a function". batr being the module, test (or avajs) being the submodule. I was requiring avajs ('ava').default, but had forgotten the .default-part. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example creates a `fruit` module that exports both the `apple` module and the `banana` module.

#### apple.js

```
function eatApple() {
  return 'Yummy apple!';
}

module.exports = { eatApple };
```

#### banana.js

```
function eatBanana() {
  return 'Yummy banana!';
}

module.exports = { eatBanana };
```

#### fruit.js

```
module.exports = {
  apple: require('./apple'),
  banana: require('./banana')
};
```

#### app.js

```
const fruit = require('./fruit');
console.log(fruit.apple.eatApple(), fruit.banana.eatBanana());
```

#### app.js (alternate)

```
const { apple, banana } = require('./fruit');
console.log(apple.eatApple(), banana.eatBanana());
```

Comment: Thanks, @Wyck! I'll try down this path a bit more.

Comment: I was requiring avajs ('ava').default, but had forgotten the .default-part. Not sure if that was the problem, but did the exports and require as in fruit.js. Thank's for your help, @Wyck !